# Installing GLscene in Delphi 10 Seattle bds

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-10-seattle

Before upgrading to *Delphi 10 Seattle* I got a demo copy in the site and tried  to install *GLscene* following strictly the instructions in `file:///C:/GLScene_VCL/_Installation/Installation.htm`.

Everything was going well and I could go up to the step 10 without serious problems including the “Compile All From Here”. It compiled correctly.
Nevertheless when  I tried to “Install every DesignTime package of visual components to RAD Studio palette pages” in all of them I get an error of *Access Violation …* in module BDS.exe.
I installed and re-installed the Delphi 10 and tried other times without success. I am almost sure that the cause is something related to the path of the libraries.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: *I am almost sure that the cause is something related to the path of the libraries.* That doesn't sound likely to me, but it you are sure, then so be it.

Comment: It might be a path problem if one of the GL packages relies on a package  and there's an outdated version being found via the path.  What I would do is firstly to open one of the GL design-time packages and see if I could build and install it manually. If that didn't smoke the problem out, I'd run one instance of the IDE in another instance and try to load one of the GL packages into it.

Comment: I tried to install one by one the design packages. In all the times it seems that will work but at the last moment the message about bds.exe come Related to bds.exe which could be the differences between the library path for XE7 and Delphi10 ? Possibly the cause is here Is there anyone using successfuly GLscene with Delphi 10 Seattle ?

Comment: Instead of guessing, why not debug?

Comment: I wrote to Embarcadero and  they sent me a licensed copy for some days for trying to install successfully the GLscene. GLscene / OpenGL is one of the most used free3D libraries in the World
Although using successfully GLscene for years with Delphi7, Delphi 10 and XE7 it seems that there is incompatibility for Delphi10  always related to bds.exe). More information in this post of GLscene forum
http://sourceforge.net/p/glscene/discussion/93606/thread/77ed17ce/